# Update state in actor from within a future

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Consider the following code sample:

```
class MyActor (httpClient: HttpClient) {

  var canSendMore = true

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case PayloadA(name: String) => send(urlA) 
    case PayloadB(name: String) => send(urlB)

    def send(url: String){
       if (canSendMore) 
          httpClient.post(url).map(response => canSendMore = response.canSendMore)
       else { 
          Thread.sleep(5000) //this will be done in a more elegant way, it's just for the example.
          httpClient.post(url).map(response => canSendMore = response.canSendMore)
       }
    }
}
```

Each message handling will result in an async http request. (post return value is a Future[Response])
My problem is that I want to safely update counter ( At the moment there is a race condition)

BTW, I must somehow update counter in the same thread, or at least before any other message is processed by this actor.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on this `canSendMore`? Because blocking an actor from processing request kind of defeats it's purpose.

Comment: In general this is true. The idea behind this actor is to orchestrate the requests sent to an external resource, which tell me (on the reponses) how many more requests I can send before requests are going to be dropped. The sleep is bad, and can be written differently, but the idea, is to block farther requests to the external resources. I thought about using the actor in order to use shared state between all type of requests to this resource which will indicate if more requests can be sent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use become + stash combination to keep on stashing messages when the http request future is in process.

```
object FreeToProcess

case PayloadA(name: String)

class MyActor (httpClient: HttpClient) extends Actor with Stash {

  def canProcessReceive: Receive = {
    case PayloadA(name: String) => {
      // become an actor which just stashes messages
      context.become(canNotProcessReceive, discardOld = false)

      httpClient.post(urlA).onComplete({
        case Success(x) => {
          // Use your result
          self ! FreeToProcess
        }
        case Failure(e) => {
          // Use your failure
          self ! FreeToProcess
        }
      })
    }
  }

  def canNotProcessReceive: Receive = {
    case CanProcess => {
      // replay stash to mailbox
      unstashAll()
      // start processing messages
      context.unbecome()
    }

    case msg => {
      stash()
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! this is not exactly what I need. I updated my question. So I basically want to create kind of push back mechanism. So if for example the actor processed PayloadA, which should have caused state to become false, I don't the actor to process PayloadB and invoke the http request.

Comment: @Tomer Changed my answer to fit your need.